# $ not working in an external js file included in Typo3

Tags: javascript, jquery, typo3

I included a javascript file in typoscript (typo3 6.2) , but I can't select anything using the $ selector , the console tells me that $ is not defined . I'm quite sure that the javascript file is successfully included because when I use the document.getelement... selectors they work fine .

I have no  idea why this is happening ? 
any idea ??

thanks

Comment: Have you included jQuery.js, and is it included before the JS file referencing the `$` variable? `document.getelement...` working wouldn't mean that the script is included correctly as that is part of vanilla JS.

Comment: I didn't but i read somewhere that the typo3 cms comes with jquery library already included , but your answer makes at least sense and pushed me right now to test whether it's included or no . Thanks

Comment: @RAKIBIANass, that's partially truth, TYPO3 has jQuery included (mainly for BE purposes), but it doesn't mean it includes it automatically everywhere, i.e. when creating your template from the scratch there's no reason to _force_ you to use jQuery, as you might prefer some other JS lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't include jQuery file and/or your jQuery is included too late (i.e. after including your JS file)

Use browser's dev tools to check the order of inclusions.

Answer (score 0):

The main jQuery library is missing or isn't inialized properly (i.e. you're trying to access functions from it before you include it to your page).

Make sure that it is loaded before any other parts of your page try to use the `$` selector.

In layman terms put

```
<script src="js/lib/jquery-1.10.2-CUSTOM.js"></script>
```

before other scripts..